# I can't find where a hook is being defined in a plugin - Easy Digital Downloads

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

I've been reading the code of the plugin "*Easy Digital Downloads*" in order to learn more about plugin development techniques. I'm getting crazy because of a hook I can't manage to find where is being defined.

```
add_action( 'edd_edit_user_profile', 'edd_process_profile_editor_updates' );
```

Located in: includes/shortcodes.php
Line: 918

I know `edd_process_profile_editor_updates` is the function used to process the profile updates (duh, obvious), and `edd_edit_user_profile` is the hook location that triggers the function, but I haven't been able to find where is being defined `do_action('edd_edit_user_profile')`

Yes, I did a full search for `edd_edit_user_profile` in the whole plugin but this is the only line that mention this hook.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sometimes the prefix or the actions are variables, like `PREFIX.'_edit_user_profile'` or `"edd_{$action}_{$current_screen}"`. try doing a folder contents search for `do_action` instead and see if what you're after is in there. if all else fails contact the author.

Comment: a way of finding the call path is to call this function in `edd_process_profile_editor_updates` : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php

Comment: Hi @mmm I think you rejected my edit on David Sword answer by mistake. Your rejection reason says: *the code is a quote of existing code in the plugin then it must remain in this state even if the code is not optimised.* but I'm not modifying the the plugin code, I'm just referencing the correct function because the one in the original answer its not the one used for my specific question and this may lead to confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in

```
includes/actions.php
```

there's

```
function edd_post_actions() {
    $key = ! empty( $_POST['edd_action'] ) ? sanitize_key( $_POST['edd_action'] ) : false;
    if ( ! empty( $key ) ) {
        do_action( "edd_{$key}", $_POST );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'edd_post_actions' );
```

in

```
templates/shortcode-profile-editor.php
```

there's

```
..input type="hidden" name="edd_action" value="edit_user_profile" ..
```

---

which, if the two are used together, would make

```
do_action( 'edd_edit_user_profile', $_POST );
```

As I said in my comment on your post - its very common in WP for actions to be dynamic, so you need to be less specific on your search, exempting the prefix, variable actions, or just remove the key and search a large `do_action` query instead.

Comment: Great! This is exactly why I like to learn this way. This is the kind of techniques you don't normally get in tutorials. I totally see the potencial.

Comment: David, I'll fix your answer.
The function defining the hook for my specific question is in `includes/actions.php`, technically is the same but lets fix this , one looks for `edd-action` which is for admin-actions, the other looks for `edd_action` which is for front-end actions.

Comment: Nice answer! Here's a little regex that will limit search results for `do_action()` to those using a dynamic string: `do_action\((.*)[.|{]` I use grep for searching within files.

Comment: I definitely need to learn regular expressions asap